# How to get rid of ambiguous column name error in rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I joined 2 tables (Modes and Prices) and need to get data from both, but I'm getting error ambiguous column name 'min_weight'. How can I specify them in order to get rid of this error?

**tables**

```
Modes: id, name, min_weight, max_weight, fixed_fee
Prices: id, min_weight, max_weight, price_per_km, mode_id
```

**queries**

```
@prices = Price.all.where(mode_id: @modes.ids).where('min_weight <= ?', @products_weight).where('max_weight >= ?', @products_weight).select("price_per_km")

@modes_prices = @modes.joins(:prices).where(prices: {id: @prices.ids}).select("modes.*, prices.price_per_km")
```

**expect**

```
I expect to get from @modes_prices: mode.min_weight, mode.max_weight, price.price_per_km
```

Comment: you have the same column name in the two tables. try prefixing it with the table:

`min_weight <= ?` => `prices.min_weight <= ?`

Comment: depending on rails version you could use `min_weight: ..@products_weight` alternatively the following will work regardless of version `Product.arel_table[:min_weight].lteq(@products_weight)` you can apply the same to max weight using `@products_weight..` or `gteq` respectively

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Ruby nor its syntax, but error you got is relatively *frequent* in SQL. It says that - when you select rows from two (or more) tables that have columns with the same name, the SQL *engine* doesn't know which table's column you meant to use and it is *ambiguous* to it.

For example, in Oracle:

```
SQL> with
  2  modes (id, name, min_weight) as             --> both tables have MIN_WEIGHT
  3    (select 1, 'apple', 10 from dual),
  4  prices (id, min_weight) as                  --> column
  5    (select 1, 20 from dual)
  6  select min_weight                           --> OK, but - which one is it?
  7  from modes join prices on modes.id = prices.id;
select min_weight
       *
ERROR at line 6:
ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined


SQL>
```

Line #6 is `select min_weight`. What's wrong with it? Oracle doesn't know which min_weight you want to fetch: is it the one that belongs to `modes`, or the one that belongs to `prices` table (as both of them contain that column)?

*Solution* is to precisely instruct SQL what you wanted by preceding column name with its table name (or table's alias):

```
  6  select prices.min_weight                  --> specify table name
  7  from modes join prices on modes.id = prices.id;

MIN_WEIGHT
----------
        20

SQL>
```

Line #6 is now `select prices.min_weight` and it is clear that I want value that belongs to `prices` table.

---

You should do the same. For example:

```
No : @prices = Price.all.where(mode_id: @modes.ids).where('min_weight <= ?'
Yes: @prices = Price.all.where(mode_id: @modes.ids).where('@modes.min_weight <= ?'
                                                            ------
                                                   specify table name
```

Once again: I don't know Ruby and that maybe isn't "it", but - the root cause *is* the same - you should specify table name along with column name.

Comment: I got what you meant but I still couldn't build the query. Still trying...

Comment: You'd want to use `where('modes.min_weight <= ?', ...)`, `@modes` is a Ruby instance variable, `modes` would be the table name.